# Algorithm for partial order width

Tags: algorithms, partial-order

I want to compute the partial order width i.e. the size of the maximum antichain in a given partial order.

By Dilworth's Theorem this is the same as minimal chains required to decompose the graph, but I cannot find any algorithms to compute any of these equivalent quantities.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).